# Why doesnt JAXB send unmarshal events for instances of class created by using mapSimpleTypeDef?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have a problem with JAXB. It is to do with using the mapSimpleTypeDef to create Java classes for named simple types.

So if I include the mapSimpleTypeDef binding in my XML Schema, I can ensure all simple types have a class generated for them.

```
 <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings mapSimpleTypeDef="true" />
 </xs:appinfo>
```

So in my XML schema if I have something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Max35Text">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

It would generate a java class called Max35Text.

If I remove the mapSimpleTypeDef then a String is used instead.

When I unmarshal an XML file into the generated classes, I use a listener like this.

```
class MyListener extends Unmarshaller.Listener
{
  public void beforeUnmarshal(java.lang.Object arg0, java.lang.Object arg1)
  {
    super.beforeUnmarshal(arg0, arg1);
  }

  public void afterUnmarshal(java.lang.Object arg0, java.lang.Object arg1)
  {
    super.afterUnmarshal(arg0, arg1);
  }
}

JAXBContext  cont = JAXBContext.newInstance("....");
Unmarshaller umarshaller = cont.createUnmarshaller();
umarshaller.setListener(new MyListener());
```

Now my problem is that normally JAXB will send all unmarshal events to the listener.

However it seems that JAXB does not register instances of classes, created by using the maxSimpleTypeDef.

Instances of the class I mentioned above, Max35Text, do not seem to register as an unmarshal events. So my listener does not anything about them. All the other class instances get unmarshal events created for them normally and get sent to my listener.

Can anyone tell me why is this?